# JComboBox disappears outside of JTable when JComboBox inside JTable cell is clicked

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jbutton, jcombobox

I am somewhat new to programming with Java. I am in the process of creating a program that can add items to a to-do list by clicking a button.

I have added a JComboBox dropdown list inside the cells of the table and I have the same comboBox displayed underneath the table in between the user input JTextField and the "Add to List" button.

The problem is: when I click the JComboBox inside the table cell, the JComboBox in between the user input and add to list button disappears. Does anyone know what causes this to disappear???

I am using Eclipse to run my java programs and I have linked screenshots below.

**NOTE: This project isn't complete so not all functionalities work yet. The user input and add to list button is not functional yet.
[snip 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1U4x.png)
[snip 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgbXJ.png)

```java
package list;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

public class EditableTable {

  public static void main(String[] a) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("To-Do List");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JTextField input = new JTextField("Enter the to-do item");
    input.setBounds(10,100,200,30);
    frame.add(input);

    JButton button = new JButton("Add to List");
    button.setBounds(400,100,100,30);
    frame.add(button);

    String[] columnTitles = { "To-Do Item", "Category", "Completed?" };
    Object[][] dataEntries = { { "Toy Story 3", "Movie/TV Show", new Boolean(false) },
                  { "Stranger Things 3", "Movie/TV Show", new Boolean(false) },
                  { "Game of Thrones", "Movie/TV Show", new Boolean(false) },
                  { "Deep Sea Fishing ", "Adventure", new Boolean(true) }, };
    TableModel model = new EditableTableModel(columnTitles, dataEntries);
    JTable table = new JTable(model);
    table.createDefaultColumnsFromModel();

    String[] cateogry = { "Movie/TV Show", "Adventure", "Food", "Other"};
    JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(cateogry);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox));
    comboBox.setBounds(230,100,130,30);
    comboBox.setSelectedIndex(0);
    frame.add(comboBox);

    frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));

    frame.setSize(600, 200);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

}

class EditableTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
  String[] columnTitles;

  Object[][] dataEntries;

  int rowCount;

  public EditableTableModel(String[] columnTitles, Object[][] dataEntries) {
    this.columnTitles = columnTitles;
    this.dataEntries = dataEntries;
  }

  public int getRowCount() {
    return dataEntries.length;
  }

  public int getColumnCount() {
    return columnTitles.length;
  }

  public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
    return dataEntries[row][column];
  }

  public String getColumnName(int column) {
    return columnTitles[column];
  }

  public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
    return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
  }

  public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
    return true;
  }

  public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int column) {
    dataEntries[row][column] = value;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create one JComboBox for the JTable and a separate one for your formular. Reusing the same variable will not work or give you strange results.

```
...
String[] cateogry = { "Movie/TV Show", "Adventure", "Food", "Other"};
JComboBox tableComboBox = new JComboBox(cateogry);
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(tableComboBox));

JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(cateogry);
comboBox.setBounds(230,100,130,30);
comboBox.setSelectedIndex(0);
frame.add(comboBox);
...
```